Annotation API in elastic search
Need help on Annotation API on transactions in elastic search. I have tried to create for one of my .Net service below is the code I run in kibana dev tools:
POST /api/apm/service/1ACT/annotation
{
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'kbn-xsrf: true' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic ${API_KEY}' \ 
-d '{
      "@timestamp": "2024-05-10 12:00:00", 
      "service": {
        "version": "1.2" 
      },
      "message": "Deployment of 1.2" 
    }'
}

Error:
Error code 400,
Bad request.

I have tried without braces after post and by adding kbn:/api/APM/service/annotation. Still no use.
Please help out how to resolve this issue ?


I have tried without braces after post and by adding kbn:/api/APM/service/annotation. Still no use.
Please help out how issue ?


Your timestamp doesn't seem to be properly formatted.
2024-05-10T12:00:00Z

I have tried with below format still did not work : 2024-05-10T12:00:00.100Z

Can someone help here ?

Ensure that the endpoint is correct. Is it "services" (not "service")?

Hello,  Thank you for reply.  It's service only. Issue still exist, not sure what to change
